# How to share a variable globally in python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, python-click

I'm working on a program which has a config. I need to use a different config for the tests and the normal running of the program.

I manage all the software and tests using a `manage.py`script and all the tests are under `python manage.py test ...`  (eg: `python manage.py test all`, `python manage.py test db`, ...)

To choose the config I did in the `__init__.py` of the config:

```
is_testing = sys.argv[1] == 'test'
if is_testing:
    from app.config.own import TestConfig as Config
else:
    from app.config.own import Config
```

and after I import the config from this file.

But sometime the test runner takes the first place in the argv so the test is in argv[2] or sometimes I run the tests by launching the script directly and not the `manage.py`.

My question is by which ways can I share a variable across the full codebase?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could completely extract determining config from your config class and just have the script accept a CLI arg of the config path to execute.  This would allow any config to be used.

`python manage.py test --config=import.path.to.settings`

Then you would have to map config to loadding the actual module.  Django does this exact thing with their `settings` file, you could consult that for implementation details

---

Also I'd def recommend using `argsparse`, which would allow you to not have to deal with `sys.argv[1]` it provides type enforcement, documenation generation, positional and keyword arg support